# By Cauchy I theorem on limits of sequence I am getting sequence is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

By Cauchy II Theorem on Limits ,

If $<S_{n}>$ is a sequence such that $S_{n}>0$ , $\forall n$ and $Lim_{n\to\infty}S_{n}=l$

Then, $Lim_{n\to\infty}$$(S_{1}S_{2}$...$S_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$=l

And , By Cauchy I Theorem on Limits ,

If $<S_{n}>$ is a sequence such that $S_{n}>0$ , $\forall n$ and $Lim_{n\to\infty}S_{n}=l$

$Lim_{n\to\infty}$${\frac{(S_{1}+S_{2}+...+S_{n})}{n}}$=l

Now, for $Lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[\big(\frac{1}{2}\big) \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{2}...\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{n}\Big]^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is convergent by using Cauchy II theorem ,as

$a_{n}=\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{n} \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{n}=0$

But is not convergent by Cauchy I Theorem ,

Let $t= \Big[\big(\frac{1}{2}\big) \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{2}...\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{n}\Big]^{\frac{1}{n}}$

taking logarithm on both sides ,we get

$log(t)={\frac{1}{n}}\Big[log\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)+log\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{2}+...+log\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{n}\Big]$

By using Cauchy I Theorem ,we get

$a_{n}=log\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{n}=n * log\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)$

$Lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=Lim_{n\to\infty}n * log\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)=\infty $

$\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}log(t)=\infty$

$t=e^{\infty}=\infty$

$Lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[\big(\frac{1}{2}\big) \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{2}...\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{n}\Big]^{\frac{1}{n}}=\infty$ .

Hence sequence diverges !!

By Cauchy I theorem on limits of sequence I am getting sequence is divergent and but using second I am getting it is convergent .

Please help me tell me where I am getting wrong !!

Comment: Please type out the part relevant to the question using MathJax and do away with the image.

Comment: Please tell me, where i have done  gone wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log(1/2) <0$ so
$n\log(1/2) \to -\infty$.